# Mockito mock NullPointerException, don't know what else is there to try

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mocking, mockito

Java thinks my mocked Course class object is null at the line when().thenReturn().

```
class StudentTest {

    @Mock
    Course courseMock1;      

    @Test
    void student_getTeacherNames_should_return_list_of_full_names() {    
        when(courseMock1.getEAP()).thenReturn(1);
    }


public class Course {
    public Course(String courseName, String name, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, Integer EAP, Teacher teacher) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.name = name;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.EAP = EAP;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
    public Integer getEAP() {
        return EAP;
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class StudentTest{...
```

--

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

--

```
@Rule public Mocks mocks = new Mocks(this);
```

none of which solve NPE.

Also tried (using mocked Teacher object as one of the parameters)

```
@Mock
Course courseMock1 = new Course(params..);
```

which yielded:
*MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'*

Comment: The simplest version is `Course courseMock = Mockito.mock(Course.class)`, but note that you should not be mocking a data class; just create an instance where `eap` is 1.

Comment: This works! So there's something wrong with annotations? Also, beginner question, what type of instance where eap is 1? What is bad about mocking a data class?

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with annotations, it's just that annotation-supporting infrastructure is more complicated than `mock(Course.class)`, and in general it's best to keep things as simple as possible. Data classes shouldn't be mocked because they don't _do_ anything, they just have values, so `new Course("courseName", "name", LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now(), 1, null)` gives you the EAP==1 you need without unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `StudentTest` class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Declare `StudentTest` class as `public`.

Declare `student_getTeacherNames_should_return_list_of_full_names` method as `public`.

Run the test class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StudentTest {

    @Mock
    Course courseMock1;      

    @Test
    public void student_getTeacherNames_should_return_list_of_full_names() {    
        Mockito.when(courseMock1.getEAP()).thenReturn(1);
        assertThat(courseMock1.getEAP()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: MockitoException: 
No tests found in StudentTest
Is the method annotated with @Test?
Is the method public?   Also, NPE persists

Comment: > Is the method public? Did you declare `student_getTeacherNames_should_return_list_of_full_names` as `public`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also have another @Test in the test class, a non-public one. This one doesn't seem to be now recognized either. The second test "should" in theory use mocks but I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: And you are getting NPE because probably you didn't add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation.

Comment: The second method is not added in question. Isolate the issue. Solve it. Then, move to next issue.

Comment: I certainly did. After adding @Runwith and making class and tests public even chrylis's working solution (Course courseMock1 = Mockito.mock(Course.class)) no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

What test framework are you using ? junit 4 or junit 5 ?

If junit5 , then the test class should be annotated with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

An alternative could be to rely purely on code (not using annotation). 
The code would become

```
class StudentTest {
    Course courseMock1 = Mockito.mock(Course.class);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use @Mock annotations you need to import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations; and call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks. Note that the method has to be called before each test.

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

I used mistakenly @Before instead of @Before**Each**